How can I improve the accuracy of ChatGPT in Prolog?
How can I design a ChatGPT alternative that recognises patterns in algorithm specifications in Prolog and maps input to output?
I need recursive patterns in nested list form with [r,"a"] for ["a","a"] and [r,[1,[r,"b"]]] for [1,"b","b",1,"b","b"] and variables 'A1', 'B2', etc. for unique items and constant values where values recur in specs. This context-free grammar could be used to write an algorithm, translate some languages or parse a list. In addition, I need maps from this recursive structure to the output recursive structure, for example a->b is map [1]->[1], c in [a,c]->[b,c] is [1,2]->[1,2] (a multidimensional address system where the column numbers are the dimensions of the term).
The first example is a list to be parsed into a recursive pattern.
[2, 
[
[[input,[['A',[1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,2,3]]]],[output,[['B',[3]]]]],
[[input,[['A',[1,2,4,2,4,1,2,4,2,4]]]],[output,[['B',[4]]]]]
]
]

The second example is a parser that takes input and produces output:
[11,
[
[[input,[['A',[[["aa,]",b,"c",[]],1]]]]],[output,[['B',["aa,]",b]]]]],
[[input,[['A',[[["cc,]",d,"e",[]],1]]]]],[output,[['B',["cc,]",d]]]]]
]
]

This can work with multiple specs to form variables and constants.
The third example is an interpreter (or will be one with additional commands):
[12,
[
[[input,[['A',[a,is,1,"+",1]]]],[output,[['B',[
[[n,"+"],[1,1,[v,a]]]]]]]],
[[input,[['A',[b,is,3,"+",4]]]],[output,[['B',[
[[n,"+"],[3,4,[v,b]]]]]]]],
[[input,[['A',[a,is,1,"-",1]]]],[output,[['B',[
[[n,"-"],[1,1,[v,a]]]]]]]],
[[input,[['A',[b,is,3,"-",4]]]],[output,[['B',[
[[n,"-"],[3,4,[v,b]]]]]]]]
]
]


The answers are as follows:
2.

[[[r,[1,[r,[2,'C1']]]]],[output,[['C1']]]]

[[[1,2,2,2,2],[[1,1]]]]

This means the patterns are repeated, then these are repeated, and the variable is output.
The map means that C1 is moved to its output position.
11.

[["[","[",'C1','C2','C3',"[","]","]",1,"]"],[output,[['C1','C2']]]]

[[[1,3],[[1,1]]],[[1,4],[[1,2]]]]

The pattern contains brackets as strings because otherwise, these would be confused with the recursive syntax.
The map moves each of the relevant variables across except C3.
12.

[['C1',is,'C2','C3','C4'],[output,[["[","[",n,'C3',"]","[",'C2','C4',"[",v,'C1',"]","]","]"]]]]

[[[1,1],[[1,11]]],[[1,3],[[1,7]]],[[1,4],[[1,4]]],[[1,5],[[1,8]]]]

This pattern translates a form of Prolog to List Prolog. The code could then be run by an interpreter.
The map swaps and moves the order of the variables to their respective places.
Spec to Algorithm, the algorithm that produces these results is fun to work on, but it's more fun to work on them myself!

Spec to Algorithm may be found at https://github.com/luciangreen/Philosophy/blob/d117f461c2ebc699edf4661dfb5015cb0b4c926b/s2a/spec_to_algorithm.pl#L4
